# CSS hover effect is not working on my code

Tags: html, css

Below code works fine in ie 9 and doesn't work in any other browser. When I mouse hover on list background should change the color, but it doesn't.

```css
.menunews ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menunews a {
  display: block;
  color: #266CAE;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.72em;
  line-height: 2.75em;
  text-indent: 2.02em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menunews li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color- stop(47%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  color: #266CAE
}
```

```html
<ul style="font-size:12px;">
  <li class="menunews">
    <a href=""><span style="margin-left:2px;">Hello test</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: menunews class you have mentioned it for the li ,hence the css should have been       li.menunews a:hover{....}

Comment: does your parent div of the ul have .menunews class??, because you have written the css that way,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/L767M/ check out this jsfiddle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

hey actually you made the **CSS** in some other way that's why browsers doesn't understand your **css code** so i made some changes in your **css** and its working fine on all browsers as per your requirement so i hope this will help you.....

```css
ul li.menunews {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  
    list-style:none; 
    height:30px;
}
ul li.menunews a {
    display:block;
    color:#266CAE;
    text-decoration:none;
}
    
ul li.menunews:hover {
    background:#ffffff;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); 
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color- stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); 
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );color:#266CAE} 
}
```

```html
<ul style="font-size:12px;">
    <li class="menunews"><a href="#"><span style="margin-left:2px;">Hello test</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define your class in ul instead of li so as to take effect :

```
<ul class="menunews" style="font-size:12px;"><li ><a href="#" >
```

Comment: Here’s a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/RZVma/) of this fix. That demo also has reformatted HTML and CSS to make the code easier to read and edit, and I fixed two occurences of a hyphen having a space after it that should not be there (`text- decoration` and `color- stop`).

Answer (score 2):

you have mentioned `menunews` class to `li`, the css should have been `li.menunews` ,use the below css code

```
 ul{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   list-style-type:none;
 }
 .menunews a{
        display:block;
        color:#266CAE;
        height:30px;
        background:#ffffff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid  #ccc;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:100%;
        height:2.72em;
        line-height:2.75em;
        text-indent:2.02em;
        text- decoration:none;
        }

 li.menunews a:hover{
      background:#ffffff;
      background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); 
      background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color- stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); 
      background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
      background:-o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
      background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
      background:linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); 
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );
      color:#266CAE;
      }
```

Please see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/L767M)**